# CakePhp Append Language to the Url if not exist

Tags: internationalization, routes

I am very new in CakePHP
and I am trying to append the language to the URL in case the user type: 
mydomain(dot)com/users

Then the Url has to change to http://mydomain.com/eng/users

Well, I am using Translate behavior and in my routes.php file I have :

```
Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/*', array(), array('lang' => '[a-z]{3}'));   
Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('lang' => '[a-z]{3}'));
```

Ok so far everything works perfectly.
But when in my contorllers/AppController.php I try to append the url I get an error

This is what I have in my afterFilter function:

```
if (empty($this->params['lang']) ){
  //Redirect to a language url 
  $this->redirect(array(
  'lang'=> 'eng', 
  'controller' => $this->params['controller'], 
  'action' => $this->params['action'])
); 


}
```

This works but when I try to go to the http:/mydomain.com/users/View/4
in the url I can see http:/mydomain(dot)com/eng/users/View/4
but what I see in the browaer is http:/mydomain(dot)com/users/View/

My question for you would be : What is the best way to achieve what I need ?
There is a plugin for doing this? or how can I handle this in CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

Well The problem was in my router.php

I had ---> 
                                                             Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/*', array(), array('lang' => '[a-z]{3}')); 
Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('lang' => '[a-z]{3}'));

And the right way is ----->
Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('lang' => '[a-z]{3}'));       Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/*', array(), array('lang' => '[a-z]{3}'));